# Left Outer Join with condition on the joinee

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have the following schema

```
users
+-------+------------+
| Field | Type       |
+-------+------------+
| id    | integer    |
+-------+------------+


posts
+---------+-------------+
| Field   | Type        |
+---------+-------------+
| id      | integer     | 
| user_id | integer     |
| topic   | varchar(255)|
+---------+-------------+
```

How do I find all the users who have never created a post about Cats?  I tried this query but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT    users.* 
FROM      users 
LEFT JOIN posts 
ON        users.id = posts.user_id 
WHERE     posts.user_id IS NULL 
AND       posts.topic LIKE 'Cats'
```

This returns an empty set even when there are users who have never posted about "Cats".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will solve your problem, Have a try and let me know if helps

```
SELECT * FROM `users` INNER JOIN posts ON users.id=posts.user_id WHERE users.id NOT IN(SELECT users.id FROM `users` LEFT JOIN posts ON users.id=posts.user_id WHERE posts.topic LIKE '%cats%')
```

Comment: I tested it and it works like charm! you can use your parameters as I had used cats  in your case it will 'Cats'

Answer (score 2):

```
Try to this

SELECT    users.* 
FROM      users 
LEFT JOIN posts 
ON        users.id = posts.user_id 
WHERE     posts.topic NOT LIKE '% Cats %'
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help: `SELECT users.* FROM posts LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id WHERE posts.topic NOT LIKE %Cats% ;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the LIKE condition to the on clause.

```
SELECT    users.* 
FROM      users 
LEFT JOIN posts 
ON        users.id = posts.user_id  
AND       posts.topic LIKE 'Cats'
WHERE     posts.user_id IS NULL
```

Most of the other answers make the mistake of using `NOT LIKE` in the WHERE clause, but that will return users who have any posts without cats. So, if a user posted about cats, but also posted about something not involving cats, they would incorrectly be returned in those queries.